# How to Change joomla logo to new logo and how to add suggestion forms in joomla 1.5.22

Tags: email, joomla, settings, graphical-logo

i added new logo in media manager the name is joomla_logo_black.png and also i changed in defalt temple css file but it's not working, and also i want to add a suggestion form in my web site it's shoud contain title descreption and email id, please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what kind of joomla logo you want to replace! If there is a joomla logo in your template you can change it with the tamplate.css for sure !
If you didn't find the logo, or the image, maybe there is another css file near the template.css file.

Answer (score 0):

The image you replaced might be cached in your browser. If you right click on the image you want to replace you can usually open the image in another tab. Look at it in a new tab then refresh the page an see if it updates. If not, at least you will have the URL of the image you are replacing.

As for adding forms, there are several components for creating forms in Joomla. My favorite is ChronoForms, but there are several very highly rated and reviewed options.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms